# DataClass remove inf vals

Tags: python, json, python-dataclasses

I have a data-class

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class ModelResult:
    scorecard_calcs: dict
```

This one is then used in the Model class

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class Model:
    def predict(self, input):
        scorecard_calcs = pd.DataFrame([{'val':np.inf}, {'val':-np.inf}]).to_dict()
        return ModelResult(scorecard_calcs=scorecard_calcs)
```

Somewhere else this will be converted into json, but `inf` is not valid json.

**How can I change the `ModelResult` dataclass, so it automatically replaces all inf values with `1.7976931348623157e+308` which is valid json.**

Comment: Don't use inf when creating `scorecard_calcs`?

Comment: Mhm, that's actually the right value there and I am only changing this due to json conventions, hence I thought it would be smarter to change it in ModelResult which is then passed forward, but maybe that's the smarter way...
(This is a smplified version, the values in scorecard calcs are calculated)

Comment: That makes sense. You should adjust the "Somewhere else this will be converted into json" code. It matters how the conversion is done though, because if you used the `json` module, for example, you could pass a custom encoder that handles `inf`.

Comment: I ran the code and got `ModelResult(scorecard_calcs={'val': {0: inf, 1: -inf}})` as a result of calling `predict`. Isnt it what you are expecting?

Comment: you can use `__post_init__` if you want to change anything after `__init__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I did it with a `__post_init__` as suggested by @balderman

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import numpy as np

ALMOST_INF = 1.7976931348623157e308

@dataclass
class ModelResult:
    scorecard_calcs: dict
    pd: float

    @staticmethod
    def replace_inf(val):
        if not isinstance(val, (int, float, complex)):
            return val

        if np.isposinf(val):
            return ALMOST_INF

        if np.isneginf(val):
            return -ALMOST_INF

        return val

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.pd = self.replace_inf(self.pd)

        scorecard_calcs = pd.DataFrame(self.scorecard_calcs)
        scorecard_calcs = scorecard_calcs.applymap(self.replace_inf)
        self.scorecard_calcs = scorecard_calcs.to_dict()
```

This works, since I know for a fact that scorecard_calcs is a dict which was previously a pandas data-frame.